# Replace item in array if they coincides with item from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, replace

I have a training task to check the array for matches with another array. Found matches must be replaced with any value.

In one case, I did it, but using `for...of` something went wrong - I don’t understand why.

```
//source array
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];

//array to compare
let arrForChange = ['one', 'four', 'six'];
```

change one item from source array is easy

```
let changedArr = arr.map(el => { if( el === 'four'){ 
  return el = 4;
  } else { 
  return el = el}  }         
);
// console.log(changedArr); // one,two,three,4,five,six
```

Replacement on the list is a little more interesting. Here i use `.includes()`

```
//This variant work 
let cahngedArrFromList = arr.map(el => {
  if(arrForChange.includes(el)){
    return 'A';
  } else {
    return el;
  }  
});
// console.log(cahngedArrFromList); // A,two,three,A,five,A
```

More interesting to look for different options. Here I use `for...of` and something going wrong, the result is not what I expected - only the first value is replaced.

```
//This variant do not work  =(
let cahngedArrFromListTwo = arr.map(el => { 
  for (const item of arrForChange){
    if (item === el){
      return 'A';
    } else {
      return el;
    }
  }
});
// console.log(cahngedArrFromListTwo); // A,two,three,four,five,six
```

If you remove the condition `else`, then everything seems to work... but no

```
let cahngedArrFromListThree = arr.map(el => { 
  for (const item of arrForChange){
    if (item === el){
      return 'A';
    } /* else {
      return el;
    } */
  }
});
// console.log(cahngedArrFromListTree); // A,,,A,,A
```

Can you explain me what with `for...of` behavoir? Or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: You `return` in the first iteration of the loop. `return` will immediately terminate the loop and exit the function. Put `return` after the loop and it will work.

Comment: Why the `el = el` ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because when you do the first check you are comparing

`"one" === "one" // will return 'A'`

You do no more checks for "one" as you have returned.

Then
`"one" === "two" // will return el`

Because you return at this point again, you never check if `"four" === "two"` etc.

This is the same for every check after.  Because you return after the first check happens, you never find any other matches.  By removing the 2nd return, you keep searching the whole array to find the matches.

If you run without the 2nd return

```
let changedArrFromListThree = arr.map(el => {
  for (const item of arrForChange) {
    console.log("doesMatch? " + item + " " + el);
    if (item === el) {
      console.log("MATCH");
      return "A";
    } else {
      // return el;
    }
  }
});
```

Output is

```
doesMatch? one one 
MATCH
doesMatch? one two
doesMatch? four two
doesMatch? six two
doesMatch? one three
doesMatch? four three
doesMatch? six three
doesMatch? one four
doesMatch? four four
MATCH
doesMatch? one five
doesMatch? four five
doesMatch? six five
doesMatch? one six
doesMatch? four six
doesMatch? six six
MATCH
[ 'A', undefined, undefined, 'A', undefined, 'A' ]
```

When you run with the 2nd return

```
let changedArrFromListThree = arr.map(el => {
  for (const item of arrForChange) {
    console.log("doesMatch? " + item + " " + el);
    if (item === el) {
      console.log("MATCH");
      return "A";
    } else {
      return el;
    }
  }
});
```

Output is

```
doesMatch? one one
MATCH
doesMatch? one two
doesMatch? one three
doesMatch? one four
doesMatch? one five
doesMatch? one six
[ 'A', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six' ]
```

This makes it clearer what is happening.

Comment: Thank you!
Your explanation helped to understand what happened in `for ... of`.
I do a `return` after the loop, as @VLAZ wrote in the comment, and I get the function to execute correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to combine an index look-up with a replacement map.

If the current item in the array is in the filter list, lookup its value as a key in the replacement map and return its value. If the key does not exist in the map, return the original value.

```js
const replacements = {
  'one'   : 1,
  'two'   : 2,
  'three' : 3,
  'four'  : 4,
  'five'  : 5,
  'six'   : 6
};

let filter = [ 'one', 'four', 'six' ],
    input  = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six' ];

console.log(replaceArrayItem(input, filter, replacements));

function replaceArrayItem(arr, filterArr, replMap) {
  return arr.map(item => filterArr.indexOf(item) > -1 ? replMap[item] || item : item);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have not read about objects yet)
I will try your method too after a detailed study of the topic of objects.